# How to use plot3 restrict to a certain region in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

For example, I want to plot the function

```
f(x,y) =sin(x^2+y^2)/(x^2+y^2),       x^2+y^2 <=4π
```

In Mathematica, I can do it as following:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y^2]/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 <= 4 Pi &)]
```

Where the `RegionFunction` specified the region of x,y to plot.
[image]

Comment: have you tried searching for 3d polar plot: f(r) = sin(r^2)/r^2

Comment: @Rasman But if the region is not circle area? Like |x|+|y|<=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a not particularly elegant solution that sets the function values of the region you don't want to see to -infinity.

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-4:0.1:4, -4:0.1:4);
z = sin(x.^2+y.^2)./(x.^2+y.^2);
idx = x.^2 + y.^2 > 4*pi;
z(idx) = -Inf;
surf(x, y, z); axis vis3d;
```

***Edit***. Actually, if you try a finer grid (say -4:0.01:4) and add `shading interp` it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: MATLAB makes use of `Inf` in its built-in functions extensively, so I don't think there's any issue with elegance here.

Comment: Agree with rwong. The only flaw is that the region's edge of the plot generated by Matlab is not as smooth as Mathematica's,

Comment: @Eastsun Re: the smoothness, it is because _Mathematica_ uses adaptive sampling with more points where the function is sharply changing and fewer where it is relatively flat. On the other hand, using `meshgrid` in MATLAB samples the space evenly and can lead to jaggedness and you can end up missing "interesting" features. You can replicate this in _Mathematica_ by setting `MaxRecursions -> 0`. Compare the regular sampling with `MaxRecursions -> 0` [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eookf.png) and the default adaptive sampling [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G24ft.png) (`MaxRecursions -> 2`).

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation to 3lectrologos's solution, with emphasis on keeping what you want:

```
x = -4*pi:0.01:4*pi;
y = -4*pi:0.01:4*pi;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Clean = (X.^2 + Y.^2)<=4*pi;
Y = Y.*Clean;
X = X.*Clean;

X(~any(X,2),:) = [];
X(:, ~any(X,1)) = [];
Y(~any(Y,2),:) = [];
Y(:, ~any(Y,1)) = [];

F = sin(X.^2+Y.^2)./(X.^2+Y.^2);
mesh(X,Y,F)
```

Note that in this case, you need to make sure that (0,0) is in your solution profile.

Edit: compressing matrices for easier plotting

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I prefer 3lectrologos's solution.